# How to remove rows from a dataframe based on another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been try my level best to compare two data frames in a specific manner but not successful. I hope experts over here can help with solution.

Below is my problem description:
I have two dataframes.

Data frame #1 looks like this.

```
df1:
pid  name  age
121  John   36
132  Mary   26
132   Jim   46
145   Kim   50
```

Dataframe#2 looks like below

```
df2:
pid  name  age
121  John   32
132   Tom   28
132 Susan   40
155   Kim   50
```

I want to compare both df's in such a way that those rows in df2 which don't have the same pid's in df1 should be deleted.

My new data frame #2 should look like below

```
df2:
pid  name  age
121  John   32
132   Tom   28
132 Susan   40
```

Highly appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) as in

```
df2[df2.pid.isin(df1.pid)]
```

which will return only the rows of df2 whose pid is in df1.

Comment: It tried your suggestion it throws out below message: DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pid'

Comment: I forgot to mention that number of rows in df2 is higher than that of df1

Comment: I also tried with df2=df2[df2['pid'].isin(dfs['pid'])]. This is giving error : KeyError: 'pid'

Comment: Is `pid` the name of the index? If so, replace it with `index`. LMK if this still malfunctions.